# Как изменить размер двумерного std::vector?

Tags: c++, vector

Пробовал:

```
vector<vector<int>>a;
a.resize(20);
a[0].resize(20);
```

Но вылетало

Comment: А вы, наверное, обращались после этого к a[1][5]? Очевидно же, что надо делать `resize` для *всех* `a[i]` - от 0 до 19!...

Comment: но я думал что есть способ типа a.resize(x,y);?

Comment: `vector<int> a{}; a.resize(20 * 20);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все заработало только при таком объявлении:

```
vector<vector<int>> a(20, vector<int>(20,0));
```

изменяю размер:

```
a.resize(w);
for(int i = 0; i < w; i++)
    a[i].resize(h);
```

Answer (score 0):

В таких случаях лучше сразу конструировать такой  вектор:

```
vector<vector<int>> a{ vector(20, vector<int>(20)) };
```

Comment: Размер вектора будет меняться в программе

Comment: E:\c++\Новая папка\main.cpp|80|error: missing template arguments before '(' token|E:\c++\Новая папка\main.cpp|80|         error: no matching function for call to 'std::vector<std::vector<int> >::vector(<brace-enclosed initializer list>)'| ругается компилятор на объявление такое

Comment: Тут главное начальное  состояние. Если вам известно какое она должно быть изначально, то  сразу конструируйте такой вектор(это эффективнее). А если программа (функция) будет менять размер, это уже  личное дело программы(функции).  Изменяйте в программе размер как хотите _ дело хозяйское. Если компилятор не поддерживает С++!7, то шаблонный аргумент укажите.

Comment: Там лишний один `vector`, делайте так: `vector<vector<int>> a(20, vector<int>(20,0));`

Comment: @Mikhailo, я не понял_ в  смысле, как лишний?

Comment: Вот ваше объявление: https://ideone.com/L4NJWD а вот мое: https://ideone.com/JVXLL0 Мое компилируется, ваше - нет.

Comment: Все, заработало

Comment: @ARHovsepyan Вы пропустили аргумент шаблона. Наверное Вы хотели написать так: `vector<vector<int>> a{vector<vector<int>>(20, vector<int>(20))};`

Comment: @EOF,  не пропустил, новые компиляторы это прекрасно  воспринимают